Why scipy checks abs(q1) < abs(q0) before for loop in Secant method?
scipy.optimize.newton for the Secant method in this line checks the condition:
if abs(q1) < abs(q0):
    p0, p1, q0, q1 = p1, p0, q1, q0

Why do they reorder p0 and p1 after that?
As I understand it, they opt for the estimation that is farthest from the horizontal axis. Why?

That seems really odd. After this line runs, q1 and p1 will be the point with the larger absolute value. However, as q0 and p0 will be discarded before q1 and p1, that logic seems backwards.

It seems not needed, because at the lines 376-380 they check this again.

I think the intention is to make p0,q0 the best guess so far on entry. But inside the loop they then proceed to trash it with the newly calculated value. It would be worth trying it with lines 383-5 swapped p1 & p0 (preserving p0,q0 as p1,q1 and the new guess as p0,q0) to see if the results are faster and/or better or worse as a result. There may be some good reason why it is like it is but I can't immediately see it.

However, it may be reasonable to check which value is closer to zero. For example in some newton implementation you would check which value is closer to zero f(x0) or f(x1). And if f(x0) is closer to zero you would take it as a best current guess. But speaking about the secant method I don't remember any articles saying that you should store most closest to zero value as an x1 or x0.

It must be a bug(but not serious). The condition should be abs(q1) > abs(q0). Why not report the bug?

@relent95 I was not sure it was a bug. I just reported it.

Can you share the link? I can't find it here.

@relent95 Here it is the link. I asked in a previous similar question was closed long ago. Recently was tagged as a query.

The maintainer said "consider rephrasing with all requested details", such as 'Reproducing Code Example'. Just do that.
